# Push Notifications via PHP?

Tags: ios, push-notification

So I'm working on an iPhone app and I'm looking for a Push Notification service which can send push notifications via PHP. Does anyone know about a service that offers that functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is what you are looking for: 
[apple-push-notification-services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) 
 It may help you
On this site you will find code snippets and instructions for:

1. [PHP Application Installation](http://www.easyapns.com/php-source)
2. [Installing MySQL Tables](http://www.easyapns.com/mysql-tables)
3. [Configuring a Cron Job to Deliver Notifications](http://www.easyapns.com/cron-job)
4. [Adding APNs to your Apple Delegate file](http://www.easyapns.com/apple-delegate)